Unable to Forward GitHub Webhooks to Jenkins via .NET Core Proxy Service
I'm facing an issue while trying to forward GitHub webhooks to Jenkins via a .NET Core proxy service I created. Here's the setup and the problem I'm encountering:

I'm utilizing Jenkins and Traefik within a private network environment.
1.To manage GitHub webhooks, I've developed a .NET Core public proxy service capable of receiving and forwarding these webhooks to internal services.
This proxy service is publicly available and hosted on IIS on DMZ.
The proxy service code is structured as follows:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace GithubProxy.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GitController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILogger<GitController> _logger;

        public GitController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ILogger<GitController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        }

        [HttpPost("notifyCommit")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GitHubWebhook([FromBody] dynamic payload)
        {


            // Extract the secret from the payload
            //string secret = payload.GetProperty("hook").GetProperty("config").GetProperty("secret").GetString();
            //if (secret != "Ah8jQke{D]?Z(3Y}zmq%.EVX&N5J<*2PvS@[:;cxG/Mgu`#ns")
            //{
            //    return BadRequest("NOT FOUND");
            //}
            // Forward the payload to Jenkins or any other destination
            // Forward all headers except `Host`
            //HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("Host");
            //HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("Request URL");
            return ToActionResult(await ForwardPayloadToJenkins(payload, HttpContext.Request.Headers));
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForwardPayloadToJenkins(dynamic payload, IHeaderDictionary headers)
        {
            // Serialize payload to JSON
            string jsonPayload = payload.ToString();

            // Set the target URL for Jenkins
            string jenkinsUrl = "https://jenkins.xxx.xx/github-webhook/";

            // Add headers to the HttpClient's default request headers
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToString()); // Replace HeaderName and HeaderValue with actual header values
            }


            // Create the request content (payload)
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Send the POST request to Jenkins and get the response
            return await _httpClient.PostAsync(jenkinsUrl, content);
        }

        public IActionResult ToActionResult(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // If the response is successful (status code 2xx), return Ok
                return new OkResult();
            }
            else
            {
                // If the response is not successful, return an appropriate error response
                string errorMessage = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return new ObjectResult(errorMessage)
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode
                };
            }
        }
    }
}


ISSUE
When attempting to forward GitHub webhooks to Jenkins via Traefik and the proxy service, I encounter the following error response:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'InternalError'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   // More stack trace...


My expectation was that the proxy will be able to successfuly foward the request to Jenkins on my internal network

Have you tried curl -v https://jenkins.xxx.xx/github-webhook/? Does it give you a different  error message?

Yes, so basically what is happening is that  if I send the request directly  to jenkins i get a 200 ok status but when i go via my proxy i get the error message. I am now suspecting that it might have something to do with the fact that i use a local CA authority in my internal network
